# Google Maps Tutorial for PHP/MySQL not working correctly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In this Google tutorial; https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 in the 'Loading the XML File' section it talks about a function called "downloadUrl". It says "url specifies the path to either your XML file or to the PHP script that generates the file, depending if you want the XML to be dynamically updated when your database changes. It's usually easiest to have this reside in the same directory as the HTML so that you can just refer to it by filename."
The problem is, if I use put a php url into the function it doesn't work. If I put a direct link to the xml file it does. For example this call does not put the markers on the map.

downloadUrl('SCOTAxml.php?lat=39.4&lng=-94.6&dist=100', function(data) { ...

However this call does work.

downloadUrl("testxml.xml", function(data) { ...

I used the SCOTAxml.php program to create the xml exactly as its done in the tutorial. I just copied it to testxml.xml afterword in order to test the downloadUrl function.

My question if you haven't guessed yet is why won't is this not working correctly according to the way the tutorial says it should?

Thoughts? Things to check? A solution?

Thanks in advance to all the great people who help resolve these simple issues.

Comment: Are you doing this: `header("Content-type: text/xml");`?  Did you do the "Checking that XML Output Works"?  What were the results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API PHP Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225980/google-map-api-php-example)

Comment: The XML file does get created. If I copy it and put it into it's own test.xml file and change just the one line of code to; downloadUrl("testxml.xml", function(data) { ... then yes it works. I had to remove the "header(..." code because it would cause the program to error out. Is there another way to set it if it is that important?

Comment: It is important if you need the browser to treat it as XML.  What error was it causing?  That needs to be done before any data is sent to the output, or it will give you an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the tutorial and it doesn't load properly due to the map icons. The link for them is dead. You will need to download your own icons. The icons used in the map can be obtained from [**Visual Case**](http://www.visual-case.it/cgi-bin/vc/GMapsIcons.pl) by clicking and saving.

```
var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'icons/restaurant.png',
        shadow: 'icons/restaurant_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'icons/bar.png',
        shadow: 'icons/bar_shadow.png'
      }
    };
```

As commented check you are generating valid XML from `SCOTAxml.php`.

**EDIT**

This is the XML file generated from tutorial as shown in browser.

```
<markers>
<marker name="Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too" address="939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.386337" lng="-122.085823" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Amici's East Coast Pizzeria" address="790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.387138" lng="-122.083237" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

I notice you are passing parameters (lat,lng & distance) which are not required in `phpsqlajax_genxml.php`. This would indicate to me that you are mixing the tutorial [**Creating Store Locator**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=en) with the one you indicated above.

[image: Map]

**EDIT 2**

To output XML content from PHP file the content-type header has to be set. This is so that the browser knows that the output content from PHP file is XML instead of default content-type header (text/html).

```
//Set content-type header for XML 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

**EDIT 3**
the icon page on visual-case has been moved here: http://www.lass.it/Web/viewer.aspx?id=4

Comment: Yes, I modified the tutorial to use my own data, but I used the same (mostly) variable names. The "distance" variable is actually created in the MySQL query.

Comment: Is your XML showing in browser as in my EDIT. As you are passing distance as a parameter for your MySQL query I suggest you have a look at the Store Locator example.

Comment: I've set up an online example at; http://bsaroundtable.org/SCOTAmap.php, if you run that you can see exactly what the xml produces, it will be displayed in a dialog box. I think I must just have a small syntax error somewhere. I just don't see it. I pass those parms to the XML so I can pull by distance from the latitude and longitude I pass it as well.

Comment: The XML generated by [SCOTAmap](http://bsaroundtable.org/SCOTAmap.php) is not well formed. It cannot be viewed in the browser except by viewing the source. If you email(see profile) me with your code I will take a look at it

Comment: I'm very happy to show you my code, I'm just not sure how to do that either. Pretty new on this site so I don't really know the procedures yet. My direct email is kcscouter at gmail dot com. If you are willing send me your eMail and we can take this offline. But then nobody else learns from it do they? Hmmmm!